# Confusion about the equations of motion for a non-local action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Given an action $$S = \int d^4x[\phi^2(x) \exp(\int d^4y F(x-y)\phi^2(y))]$$ it is straightforward enough to get the classical equations of motion, simply computing $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)}$ using the product and chain rules. My question is, how would the procedure change if the term in the exponential included derivatives, say if we had

$$S = \int d^4x[\phi^2(x) \exp(\int d^4y F(x-y)(\phi(y)+g\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(y))^2)]$$

where $g$ is some constant and the partial derivatives are with respect to the $y$ coordinates. In particular, is there any way to make sense of expressions such as $\frac{\delta }{\delta\phi(x)}\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(y)$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I don't know how well-defined such expressions might be and I'm not looking for a rigorous answer, only a way to get through the computations, so I thought it would be better suited for here.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4255129/11127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. If the action is of non-local form
   $$S[\phi]~=~\int d^4x ~\phi^2(x) e^{G[\phi;x]},$$
   then the functional derivative (whenever it makes mathematical sense) is of the form
   $$ \frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi(z)}
   ~=~2\phi(z)e^{G[\phi;z]} +\int d^4x~\phi^2(x)\frac{\delta G[\phi;x]}{\delta \phi(z)} e^{G[\phi;x]}. $$
2. Don't forget that the [Euler-Lagrange expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_two_variables_with_higher_derivatives) contains more terms if the functional contains higher-order space-time derivatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was computing it two different ways and getting two different answers, one in which the integral wasn't there on the second term. I see now what my mistake was!